# How to fill ComboBox items when text in the same combobox changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am trying to implement a textchanges event to a combobox so that the items changes based on the value entered in the same combobox.

Here is my XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBoxRoleNameDescEdit" IsEditable="True" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="ComboBoxRoleNameDescEdit_TextChanged"/>
```

And Here is the code-behind:

```
private void ComboBoxRoleNameDescEdit_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ComboBoxRoleNameDescEdit.Items.Clear();
        using (var Connect = new SqlConnection(connstr))
        {
            Connect.Open();
            using (var Command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[spParametresRolesTb_FillRoleIdComboBox]", Connect))
            {
                Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                Command.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBoxRoleNameDescEdit.Text;
                Command.Parameters.Add("@entity_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LoggedInData.LoggedInstitutionId;
                SqlDataReader dr = Command.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string classes = dr.GetString(0);
                    ComboBoxRoleNameDescEdit.Items.Add(classes);
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
            Connect.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

The problem I am encountering is that, because I need to refresh the list of items at each input, the input itself is being cleared due to this piece of code ``ComboBoxRoleNameDescEdit.Items.Clear();```. in fact, only the first input is automatically cleared, the remaining inputs are not.

Any idea how I can overcome this?

Comment: `ComboBoxRoleNameDescEdit.DataSource = null;` instead of clear and at the end use `ComboBoxRoleNameDescEdit.ResetText();`

Comment: Thanks styx, but DataSource and ResetText don't work in WPF. That must be Winform I guess.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't operate on the `ItemsControl` directly. Operate on the source collection i.e. the data model. Also you need to disable text search on the `ComboBox`.

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<string> Classes { get; set; }

  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.Classes = new ObservableCollection<string>();
  }

  public async Task FilterItemsAsync(string predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connstr))
    {
      connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
      using (var command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[spParametresRolesTb_FillRoleIdComboBox]", connection))
      {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = predicate;
        command.Parameters.Add("@entity_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LoggedInData.LoggedInstitutionId;

        using (SqlDataReader dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken))
        {    
          this.Classes.Clear();
          while (await dataReader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken))
          {
            string classes = dataReader.GetString(0);
            this.Classes.Add(classes);
          }
        }
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <ComboBox IsTextSearchEnabled="False" 
            IsEditable="True" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Classes}"
            TextBoxBase.TextChanged="ComboBox_TextChanged" />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private DispatcherTimer DelayTimer { get; set; }
  private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }
  private string FilterPredicate { get; set; }
  private bool IsFilterExecuting { get; set; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeDelayTimer();
    this.FilterPredicate = string.Empty;
  }

  private void InitializeDelayTimer()
  {
    this.DelayTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    this.DelayTimer.Tick += FilterItemsAsync_OnTimerElapsed;
    this.DelayTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800);
  }

  private void ComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!(e.OriginalSource is TextBox textBox))
    {
      return;
    }

    HandleTimer();       
    TryCancelRunningFilter();
    this.FiterPredicate = textBox.Text;
  }

  private async void FilterItemsAsync_OnTimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.IsFilterExecuting = true;
    var viewModel = this.DataContext as ViewModel;

    try
    {
      this.CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
      await viewModel.FilterItemsAsync(this.FiterPredicate, this.CancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) {}
    finally
    {
      this.DelayTimer.Stop();
      this.CancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
      this.IsFilterExecuting = false;
    }
  }

  private void HandleTimer()
  {
    // Start or reset the timer interval
    this.DelayTimer.Start();
  }

  private bool TryCancelRunningFilter()
  {
    if (this.IsFilterExecuting)
    {
      this.CancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Your current implementation is not very efficient and offers a bad user experience. On each key press the event handler will read maybe lots of data, which will freeze the UI. I recommend an asynchronous approach. Maybe even add some delay, so that not every key press, while typing a word, will trigger the filter.

Comment: Hi @BionicCode, thanks for your input but the code is throwing an exception at this line ``viewModel.FilterItems(textBox.Text);``. The exception is a NullReferenceException. Regarding the delay: You're probably right. How do you see such an implementation? Should I just check for length and fire the whole code when the input length exceeds a certain value? Thanks

Comment: The exception is likely thrown because `this.DataContext as ViewModel` returns `null`. This is because wrong type cast or unset `DataContext`. Make sure that the `DataContext` is set e.g., like in the example using XAML. Input length is not a good criteria as you never know the input length in advance. It could be everything > 0.

Comment: I updated the answer. The example uses a [`DispatcherTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=netframework-4.8#examples). It'll start on the first invocation of the `TextChanged` handler.Interval is set to 800 ms (adjust to your requirements). Whenever the handler is invoked again and the timer is not elapsed at this point, the timer will be reset. Once the user has completed the input, the timer will elapse and execute the view model's `FilterItemsAsync()` method.

Comment: Also consider to use the `Count` constraint in your SQL  query to limit the results to a reasonable count in order to shorten execution time (use data virtualization). I also changed your database handling (see `ViewModel`) to use the async API with cancellation support. The `TextChanged` handler is now full async.

Comment: thanks again for your input but the code is not working here :(. The DataContext ViewModel is not recognized, the ``FilterItemsAsync_OnTimerElapsed```is returning a wrong type, .... I didn't mention that this is my first time coding ever so I trying to avoid MVVM first. Based on the code in my program, is it not possible to provide an 'easy' solution to this...

Comment: No problem. I fixed the return type and changed it to void (copy&paste error apparently). Have you added the relevant namespaces to the MainWindow.xaml code? Otherwise the class `ViewModel` will not be recognized.

Comment: If you are tired of learning, you can use your original code. just set `ComboBox.IsTextSearchEnabled` to `False`. But as I said before, your current implementation will perform very poor on accepting user input and fetching bigger amount of data. You should get the example working and then study it to improve your skills.

Comment: As a note: the XAML code in MainWindow.xaml is not working without some adjustments e.g. adding `x:Class` and required namespaces. It's just meant to show the basic structure...

Comment: I would like to learn of course, but I have been told here and on reddit that as a beginner, I should avoid mvvm for now. Learn the basics and then move to mvvm later on. I didn't add the namespaces to the MainWindow but to the Window where the combobox is. I tried with ``ComboBox.IsTextSearchEnabled`` and it works now. Thanks

Comment: I will defintely keep your comment so that I can come back to it later on.

Comment: Yeah, disabling the text search is the main solution. Honestly, the recommendation to skip MVVM is wrong. It's quite simple. You should write a simple application first, like displaying some text. Then gradually increase the complexity like showing a collection of items etc. If you are just beginning with programming why do you use database already? You skipped some important fundamentals. Go step by step and use MVVM from the beginning. Read different articles  about it and keep it simple with your first application. Database is a later chapter, which is a complex and big field of its own.

Comment: The first steps might be hard, but it's getting easier quickly. And progress feels better the harder you worked for it. Please try to use MVVM from the very beginning. You can come back to this forum and ask for help anytime.

Comment: Thanks again for the advice. I will see how I can move to mvvm with some baby steps.